# How many values of $a$ have $1000 | (a^{100} - 1)$?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

How many integers a from 1 to 1000 are there such that $a^{100}-1$ is divisible by 1000?

I need to find how many $a$ there are such that $a^{100}\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ and $a^{100}\equiv 1\pmod{125}$, but I don't know how to go on from here.  Could I get some help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution: $\lambda(1000)=100$. so $a^{100}\equiv 1$ for all $a$ with $(a,1000)=1$. there are $\varphi(1000)=400$ such numbers.

Second solution:

$\varphi(8)=4$, so by Euler's theorem all $a^{100}=(a^{4})^{25}\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ for all odd numbers.

$\varphi(125)=100$, so all numbers that are not multiples of five satisfy $a^{125}\equiv 1$ by Euler.

Therefore you want numbers coprime to $1000$. There are $\varphi(1000)=400$.

Comment: For first solution see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: Thanks!  Also, how do we know that numbers not coprime to 1000 cannot work?

Comment: Suppose $d$ divides $a$ and $1000$. and $d$ is not $1$. Then $d$ divides $a^{100}$, so $d$ does not divide $a^{100}-1$.

Comment: Do you see how we can finish from here? If $d$ divides $1000$ but $d$ does not divide $a^{100}-1$ we conclude $1000$ does not divide $a^{100}-1$